# How to wrap string by tag in Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

I want to wrap the content of a lot of div-elements/blocks with `p` tags:

```html
<div class='value'>
  some content
</div>
```

It should become:

```html
<div class='value'>
  <p>
    some content
  </p>
</div>
```

My idea was to get the content (using bs4) by filtering strings with `find_all` and then wrap it with the new tag. Don't know, if its working. I cant filter content from tags with specific attributes/values.

I can do this instead of bs4 with regex. But I'd like to do all transformations (there are some more beside this one) in bs4.

Comment: Suppose you have a set of nested `div` elements. Would you want to wrap the contents of *all* levels of `div` elements?

Comment: No, I want to specify div-tags by attributes.

Comment: Does the code in my answer show you what you needed?

Comment: No, cause it wraps the div-elements with a complete html-structure - what I don't need.

Comment: No, no, no. Look again. It only wrapped the content of the div element. You were looking at the complete HTML that I displayed so you could see the result.

Answer (score 3):

Believe it or not, you can use [**`wrap`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#wrap). :-)

Because you might, or might not, want to wrap inner `div` elements I decided to alter your HTML code a little bit, so that I could give you code that shows how to alter an inner `div` without changing the one 'outside' it. You will see how to alter all `div`s, I'm sure.

Here's how.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(open('pjoern.htm').read(), 'lxml')
>>> inner_div = soup.findAll('div')[1]
>>> inner_div
<div>
some content
</div>
>>> inner_div.contents[0].wrap(soup.new_tag('p'))
<p>
some content
</p>
>>> print(soup.prettify())
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="value">
   <div>
    <p>
     some content
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```